# Give a right to domain user to manage his system's firewall

Tags: windows, security, group-policy

How can a we give a right to domain user to manage his system's firewall?

We're having a Windows setup, and using Windows Server 2012 for managing domain group policies.

Comment: Sorry, can someone point me what's wrong in this question? And also help me with how can I do that?

Comment: I would *guess* because its off topic, and probably one for your IT administrators. 2, could be better on Server Fault. 3, it is potentailly very broad. 4. You don't show what you've tried making it hard for us to know where to start with an answer! Although I think the down vote is harsh but some do downvote for being off topic - so please don't take down vote as personal :) ! Any way, this post will be moved for you soon enough I would think

Comment: @Dave thanks for your response. Its okay. Not sure how to do this, so we haven't tried anything yet. We googled a lot but unable to find any details on how to do it. Where should I ask this kind of question?